# Don't know why eigen() gives a vectors of wrong sign and the loading matrix is just vector

Tags: r

Don't know why eigen() gives a vectors of wrong sign and the loading matrix is just vector

> setwd("D:/BlueHDD/MAQAB/RStudio/R/PCA/Intelligence")
>
> mydata <- read.csv("Intelligence2.csv",na.strings = ".")
>
> head(mydata)

```
      M     P     C     E     H     F
1 1.000 0.620 0.540 0.320 0.284 0.370
2 0.620 1.000 0.510 0.380 0.351 0.430
3 0.540 0.510 1.000 0.360 0.336 0.405
4 0.320 0.380 0.360 1.000 0.686 0.730
5 0.284 0.351 0.336 0.686 1.000 0.735
6 0.370 0.430 0.405 0.730 0.735 1.000
```

> ii <- as.matrix(mydata[,1:6])
>
> rownames(ii)<- c ("M","P","C","E","H","F")
>
> colnames(ii)<- c ("M","P","C","E","H","F")
>
> head(ii)

```
      M     P     C     E     H     F
M 1.000 0.620 0.540 0.320 0.284 0.370
P 0.620 1.000 0.510 0.380 0.351 0.430
C 0.540 0.510 1.000 0.360 0.336 0.405
E 0.320 0.380 0.360 1.000 0.686 0.730
H 0.284 0.351 0.336 0.686 1.000 0.735
F 0.370 0.430 0.405 0.730 0.735 1.000
```

> myEIG <- eigen(ii)
>
> myEIG$values

[1] 3.3670861 1.1941791 0.5070061 0.3718472 0.3131559 0.2467257

> myEIG$vectors

```
           [,1]       [,2]         [,3]        [,4]         [,5]
[1,] -0.3677678 -0.5098401  0.266985551  0.72768020  0.047584025
[2,] -0.3913477 -0.4092063  0.485916591 -0.66464527 -0.005392018
[3,] -0.3719504 -0.3825819 -0.831626240 -0.15204371 -0.003331423
[4,] -0.4321872  0.3748248  0.021531885  0.06531777 -0.742970281
[5,] -0.4219572  0.4214599  0.002730054  0.01174474  0.665109730
[6,] -0.4565228  0.3288196  0.023032686  0.03473540  0.057617669
            [,6]
[1,] -0.04178482
[2,] -0.03872816
[3,] -0.02352388
[4,] -0.34056682
[5,] -0.44922966
[6,]  0.82365511
```

> myPCA <- princomp(covmat=ii)
>
> head(myPCA)

$sdev

```
   Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4    Comp.5    Comp.6 
1.8349621 1.0927850 0.7120436 0.6097927 0.5596033 0.4967149
```

$loadings

Loadings:

```
  Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6
M  0.368  0.510  0.267  0.728              
P  0.391  0.409  0.486 -0.665              
C  0.372  0.383 -0.832 -0.152              
E  0.432 -0.375               -0.743  0.341
H  0.422 -0.421                0.665  0.449
F  0.457 -0.329                      -0.824


               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6
SS loadings     1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000
Proportion Var  0.167  0.167  0.167  0.167  0.167  0.167
Cumulative Var  0.167  0.333  0.500  0.667  0.833  1.000
```

$center
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

$scale

```
M P C E H F 
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

$n.obs
[1] NA

$scores
NULL

> summary(myPCA) # print variance accounted for 
>   Importance of components:

```
                         Comp.1    Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4
Standard deviation     1.834962 1.0927850 0.71204360 0.60979272
Proportion of Variance 0.561181 0.1990299 0.08450101 0.06197453
Cumulative Proportion  0.561181 0.7602109 0.84471188 0.90668641

                           Comp.5     Comp.6
Standard deviation     0.55960331 0.49671489
Proportion of Variance 0.05219264 0.04112095
Cumulative Proportion  0.95887905 1.00000000
```

> loadings(myPCA) # pc loadings

Loadings:

```
  Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6
M  0.368  0.510  0.267  0.728              
P  0.391  0.409  0.486 -0.665              
C  0.372  0.383 -0.832 -0.152              
E  0.432 -0.375               -0.743  0.341
H  0.422 -0.421                0.665  0.449
F  0.457 -0.329                      -0.824


               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6
SS loadings     1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000
Proportion Var  0.167  0.167  0.167  0.167  0.167  0.167
Cumulative Var  0.167  0.333  0.500  0.667  0.833  1.000
```

> plot(myPCA,type="lines") # scree plot

Would be very grateful for kind help!

Comment: It seems you need to work on learning the basics of linear algebra. A very quick explanation as to why it is perfectly valid for the sign of eigen values to "flip" is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/205715/184400).

Comment: Understood the sign flip! Thanks!

Comment: But, why myPCA <- princomp(covmat=ii, cor = TRUE) gives loadings matrix which is actually only eigenvectors not the actual loading matrix ? Would be many thanks for kind help!  I could not find any hints onlines and on books!

Answer (score 1):

If the operation of an R function or its return value is confusion, always check the help file first.

```r
help("princomp")
```

There we see (among other things), the following:

> Value:
>       ‘princomp’ returns a list with class ‘"princomp"’ containing the following components:
>        ...
>        loadings: the matrix of variable loadings (i.e., a matrix whose columns
>        contain the eigenvectors)....
>   ...
>   Note:
>        The signs of the columns of the loadings and scores are arbitrary,
>        and so may differ between different programs for PCA, and even
>        between different builds of R: ‘fix_sign = TRUE’ alleviates that.

An explanation of why the signs are arbitrary can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/205715/184400), or indeed is readily apparent from the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors (see, e.g., [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvalue.html)).

As to why the `loadings` element just gives the eigenvectors, it's because the documentation says that's what it will return! However, as to whether you should use eigenvectors or eigenvectors multiplied by the square root of the eigenvalues, or whether you can call both or only the latter "loadings", there has historically been some back and forth or confusion on this (see [this Cross Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/loadings-vs-eigenvectors-in-pca-when-to-use-one-or-another) and its answers for some discussion on this).

Ultimately, you just have to know which your chosen function returns, and either manually adjust it, or change how you discuss what it means, or choose a different function that returns what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Understood the sign flipping issue! In my case the princomp() flip Comp3 but Eigen() flip Comp4 and Comp6, It is confusing!      Can I use similar argument in Eigen() to achieve the fix_sign=T effect        Hope you could help!